# sql oracle max(x) returning row with higher x

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I know there are several Qs on the MAX() topic with very fancy queries but i still cant solve this...

I need help with this Query on an Oracle DB:

```
select ID, Object, Result
from STable
where Date='01012000'
and Object='testobject'
and ID='002'
union select  '002' as ID, 'testobject' as Object, 0 as Result from dual
```

returning

```
ID   OBJECT     RESULT
002  testobject  0
002  testobject  42
```

i need the **row** with the higher result

Expected Output:

```
002  testobject  42
```

so my Idea was:

```
select ID, Object, max(Result) as maxresult
from(
select ID, Object, Result
from STable
where Date='01012000'
and Object='testobject'
and ID='002'
union select  '002' as ID, 'testobject' as Object, 0 as Result from dual
) group by ID, Object
```

which returns the same as above... but

```
select  max(Result) as maxresult
from(
select ID, Object, Result
from STable
where Date='01012000'
and Object='testobject'
and ID='002'
union select  '002' as ID, 'testobject' as Object, 0 as Result from dual
)
```

returning

```
MAXRESULT

42
```

and seems to work fine.

What do i miss? any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Are your ID or object columns `char` rather than `varchar2` and if so what size? That would make the IDs different, and would give this behaviour. While using `trim()` (or casting the fixed value to match) would work around this, it's almost always better to use `varchar2` to avoid this kind of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess? Either ID or object contains spaces since it should have been grouped by, so something is different between the first 002 and the second..

Try:

```
select trim(ID), trim(Object), max(Result) as maxresult
from(
select ID, Object, Result
from STable
where Date='01012000'
and Object='testobject'
and ID='002'
union select  '002' as ID, 'testobject' as Object, 0 as Result from dual
) group by trim(ID), trim(Object)
```

Comment: It would probably be better to fix the underlying issue (which I'm guessing is `char` columns) rather than work around it with trim.

Comment: No problem mate @c0pyc4t

Answer (score 1):

Your first query returns 2 rows because of the `GROUP BY`. You can apply `ORDER BY` after `UNION` and get the first row.